# Debugging Protractor with WebStorm

Tags: protractor, webstorm

So new to Protractor, so please bear with me.

So I have some simple tests written, and I can run (and sorta debug them in WebStorm). I say sorta debug, because when I run my test, it hits all breakpoints and console.logs before actually executing any of the code.  it almost like it goes through the code twice.

As an example, the first thing my test does is go to a page (after loading the landing page).

```
browser.get('/#/divisions');
```

If I set a break point after it, it will hit that break point before going to the divisions page. I thought it maybe an async/await issue, but after trying to make everything async, it did the same.

Any idea on what I might be missing?

Comment: attach your code to avoid guessing

Comment: Well the async/await solves the issue...sorta.  If everything in the test is async and awaited, then the breakpoints will hit.  There has to be an easier way to do it.